# Loading different content to modal box with one JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use one javascript file to open a modal box with different content depending on what is clicked. One modal box works great, the other ones load the correct text, but not any pictures. If I take out the div class mySlides fade and just add pictures to the modal box, it works fine. I am sure it something simple I am overlooking.

```js
// Get the modal
let modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");



// When the user click on the button, open the modal
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "flex";
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
  span[i].onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

let slideIndex = 1;

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlide(slideIndex = n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlide(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlide(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

showSlide(slideIndex);
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" class="text">Learn More</button>
<!--Modal-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <!--Full-width images with number and caption text-->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/checkbook1.jpg" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/checkbook1.jpg" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/checkbook.jpg" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <!--Next and previous buttons-->
      <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!--The dots/circles-->
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
    <h2 id="modal-heading">MyRegister App</h2>
    <p id="modal-text">This app simulates a checkbook register. Add deposits and withdraws.
    </p>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <a href="https://github.com/cpickard2790/MyRegisterGUI/tree/master/My%20Register">Source Code</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="photo-wrap">
  <img src="images/test.jpg" class="portp">
  <button id="myBtn" class="text">Learn More</button>
  <!--Modal-->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <!--Full-width images with number and caption text-->
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/practest.png" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/test.jpg" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/practest.png" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <!--Next and previous buttons-->
        <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <!--The dots/circles-->
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      </div>
      <h2 id="modal-heading">Practice Test App</h2>
      <p id="modal-text">This is a practice test application I made for work.</p>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <a href="https://github.com/cpickard2790/MyRegisterGUI/tree/master/My%20Register">Source Code</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think the text is changing correctly. Is it changing correctly?

Comment: Yes, h2 and p text is changing correctly on my end. It is just the pictures insides the mySlides div that will not show on the rest of the modal boxes, just the first modal. As soon as I get rid of the mySlides divs and just add pictures to the slideshow-container, it works on each modal box, they just arent in the nice container with the next and previous buttons, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no picture attached. I can't see is the picture is changing or not.
After reading your code, I understand that you are changing your slides from this html code.

```
<!--Next and previous buttons-->
<a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

But in your code, you are not adding the value that you are sending to `plusSlides()` function.

So, you need to make changes to your `plusSlides()` function like the following:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlide(slideIndex += n);
}
```

That's it! Your problem is solved!!!

#### BUT

**There's Still Some Problem Exist!**

You may notice that you're back button is not working as expected. That's because you have total  **6** div elements with same class name! so, here, `slides.length` actually returns 6. So, you may pass another indicator to your function from your html. And you should put separate `slideIndex` variable for keeping count of each event.

I have tried to edit your `javascript`.

Here is the full live code:

```js
// Get the modal
let modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");



// When the user click on the button, open the modal
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "flex";
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
  span[i].onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

let slideIndex = [1, 4];
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"),
  dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(counter, index) {
  showSlide((slideIndex[index] + counter), index);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(position, index) {
  showSlide(position, index);
}

function showSlide(position, index) {
  let lastPostion = index * 3 + 3,
    firstPosition = index * 3 + 1;

  if (position > lastPostion) {
    position = firstPosition;
  }
  if (position < firstPosition) {
    position = lastPostion;
  }
  slides[slideIndex[index] - 1].style.display = "none";
  dots[slideIndex[index] - 1].className = dots[slideIndex[index] - 1].className.replace(" active", "");

  slides[position - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[position - 1].className += " active";

  slideIndex[index] = position;
}

function initSlide() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[0].style.display = "block";
  dots[0].className += " active";
  slides[3].style.display = "block";
  dots[3].className += " active";
}
initSlide();
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" class="text">Learn More</button>
<!--Modal-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <!--Full-width images with number and caption text-->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/checkbook1.jpg" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/checkbook1.jpg" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/checkbook.jpg" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <!--Next and previous buttons-->
      <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!--The dots/circles-->
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(1, 0)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(2, 0)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(3, 0)"></span>
    </div>
    <h2 id="modal-heading">MyRegister App</h2>
    <p id="modal-text">This app simulates a checkbook register. Add deposits and withdraws.
    </p>
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <a href="https://github.com/cpickard2790/MyRegisterGUI/tree/master/My%20Register">Source Code</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="photo-wrap">
  <img src="images/test.jpg" class="portp">
  <button id="myBtn" class="text">Learn More</button>
  <!--Modal-->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <!--Full-width images with number and caption text-->
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/practest.png" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/test.jpg" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="images/practest.png" class="modal-image" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <!--Next and previous buttons-->
        <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <!--The dots/circles-->
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(4, 1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(5, 1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(6, 1)"></span>
      </div>
      <h2 id="modal-heading">Practice Test App</h2>
      <p id="modal-text">This is a practice test application I made for work.</p>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <a href="https://github.com/cpickard2790/MyRegisterGUI/tree/master/My%20Register">Source Code</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope, this will help your!

Comment: YES! Thank you! I had figured out the plusSlides was missing += and only had the = like 15 minutes ago. But I still had the same problem you just described I would have! Wow, thank you so much!

Comment: @chad, Thanks! This code is not refactored properly. Think about refactoring it if you get some time. :)